# On button click, I need to bind the values using React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I need to bind the values upon Button Click, I am getting Undefined,Here I am using Redux concept, So Now I worte an Action to get a Single Product,in the Component I dispatched the Action.
But I am getting Undefined(xhr.js:177 GET http://localhost:3000/users/undefined 404 (Not Found)), Please can anyone help me in this...Thanks in Advance

here is my Action Code

```
// get a product
export const fetchProduct = (productId:string) => {
    return async (dispatch:any) => {
        try {
            let dataURL : string = `http://localhost:3000/users/${productId}`;
            let response = await axios.get(dataURL);
            dispatch({type : FETCH_PRODUCT_SUCCESS , payload : response.data});
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    };
};
```

Here is my Component

```
    interface URLParamType {
        productId : string;
    }
    
    interface IProps {}
    
    interface IState {
        selectedProduct: IProduct;
        isSubmitted : boolean;
    }
    
     const UpdateProduct = () => {
    
        
    
        let dispatch = useDispatch();
        let history = useHistory();
    
        let {productId} = useParams<URLParamType>();
    
        // get product information from Redux Store
        let getalldatafromserver :allReducer.Iproducts = useSelector((state : {fetchalldata:allReducer.Iproducts})=>{
            return state.fetchalldata;
      })
    
        useEffect(() => {
            // get a single product from server and keep in the Redux Store
            console.log(getalldatafromserver);
           dispatch(allActions.fetchProduct(productId));
        }, [productId]);
    
       
    
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
            {/* <pre>{JSON.stringify(selectedProduct)}</pre> */}
            <section className="mt-3">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col">
                                <p className="h3 text-secondary">Update Product</p>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex impedit, incidunt ipsum nulla sapiente sint suscipit? A animi, error et fuga ipsum minus, nam officia praesentium quisquam, recusandae soluta voluptate?</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-4">
                                <div className="card">
                                    <div className="card-header bg-secondary text-white">
                                        <p className="h4">Update Product</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="card-body rgba-green-light">
                                        <form >
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <input
                                                    required
                                                    name="name"
                                                    // onChange={updateInput}
                                                    //  value={getalldatafromserver.products.name}
                                                    type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Name"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-group mt-2">
                                                {/* <input
                                                    name="image"
                                                    // onChange={updateImage}
                                                    className="form-control" type="file" id="formFile"/>
                                                <img src={getalldatafromserver.selectedproduct.image} alt="" width="25" height="25"/> */}
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-group mt-2">
                                                <input
                                                    required
                                                    name="price"
                                                    // onChange={updateInput}
                                                    // value={getalldatafromserver.selectedproduct.price}
                                                    type="number" className="form-control" placeholder="Price"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-group mt-2">
                                                <input
                                                    required
                                                    name="qty"
                                                    // onChange={updateInput}
                                                    // value={getalldatafromserver.selectedproduct.qty}
                                                    type="number" className="form-control" placeholder="Qty"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-group mt-2">
                                                        <textarea
                                                            required
                                                            name="info"
                                                            // onChange={updateInput}
                                                            // value={getalldatafromserver.selectedproduct.info}
                                                            rows={3} className="form-control" placeholder="Information"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-group mt-2">
<td>
                                                            <Link to={`/products/${product.id}`} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Update</Link>
                                                            <button onClick={()=> {deleteProduct(product.id as string)}} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                                                        </td>
                                                <input type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" value="Update"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
         </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the Solution, It is problem with URL params... I resloved it